# E-greeting card functionality with EE?

Tags: ee2

I'd like to recreate an "e-greeting card" functionality using EE, and I'm wondering if this could be done with the core functionality of EE, or if it would require custom programming.

The functionality is as follows.

1. User clicks on an image they like for the "front" of their e-card, and is then presented with a form with 5 fields: "From" name, "From" email, "To" name, "To" email, and "message"
2. After filling form and clicking "send", system generates the following:

   - A URL where this card now lives. The URL allows you to see the card's "front" and "back". The front is an image that the user selected. The back displays info the user entered--email, message, etc
   - An email to the recipient with another URL link where the receiver can see it
   - If the receiver clicks on the link, the sender also gets an email confirming the card was read

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Also see the question [Is there a good eCard/eVite Solution available?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13642/is-there-a-good-ecard-evite-solution-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got a image and a form to capture the content.

- You'll need to overlay the form text on the image: [CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image) can help here
- A custom URL generator (like [Solspace's Shortcut](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/shortcut/); there are others in [Devot-ee](http://www.devot-ee.com))
- Solspace's [Freeform](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) can capture the form data, including the recipient address for forwarding
- Mail notification can be done with a hidden form on the display page, triggered by something like Adam Kahn's [Send Email](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/send-email) or Mike Rog's [Email from Template](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/email-from-template)

Comment: Thanks! Can the info gathered via Freeform be displayed on a page (see first bullet of #2 above)?

Comment: I overthunk that one - you can skip Freeform. Just create a form and use safecracker to pass the form data in to an entry and then you can read it back out.