# Is there a good eCard/eVite Solution available?

Tags: php, events

For several years I have been using this [simplEcard](http://simplecard.budda.ch/) solution for a site and this year it appears that the gap between the last update to the solution and the 5.2x version of PHP has grown too wide and generates a number of PHP error.

Is anyone aware of a good eCard solution that could be integrated with EE?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the feature set that you're after? Comparable to the features simplEcard, or more? It seems like Channel Form (Safecracker) combined with Postmaster would work very well for a basic version. Or Solspace Freeform.

Comment: I'll look into those. Basically something that allows you to select an image and email it to someone like an eCard.

Comment: There is a similar question with an answer here: [E-greeting card functionality with EE?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/e-greeting-card-functionality-with-ee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically something that allows you to select an image and email it to
>   someone like an eCard.

You could address that aspect of your question with built-in functionality and one add-on.

Create a channel for storing your library of "eCard Designs" that a user can choose from.

Then another channel for "User Created eCards" and allow users to publish into this channel from the front end of your site using [Channel Form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/) (formerly SafeCracker). You'd be able to collect and store all the parameters of the eCard (to, from, message, design, etc) as custom fields.

Then in conjunction with this you can use the [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) add-on to template, dynamically fill, and deliver the email when the user creates their eCard entry.

Since this gives you the freedom of the Channel module, and since Postmaster is made to be adaptable, I think this approach would probably allow for the greatest flexibility.

Comment: Alex, thank you for taking the time to respond on this. Sounds like a good solution.